# Allow user to redefine hotkeys for Swing during runtime Java

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I have a Java application that contains a lot of features, and to make life easier for the user, I have set up numerous mnemonics and accelerators. For instance, I have a JMenuItem that allows the user to save the state of the application, witht he following code:

```
JMenuItem saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
saveItem.setMnemonic('S');
saveItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
```

This works as desired, but now I would like to give the user an option to change the hot keys. While CTRL + s would seem like a fairly obvious hot key to stick with, there are many features that use these short cuts, and simply picked Save as an example.

I have a JButton that I have arranged for testing purposes that allows the user to enter in a new shortcut when clicked. I was thinking that I would simply try and capture the keys that the user holds down (InputEvent) and presses (KeyEvent). I also though it might be smart to force the use of an InputMask to avoid complications in Text Fields and the like.

What I am wondering is: What is the best way to capture the new input that the user enters? I have looked up information regarding KeyBindings and they look right for the job, but the main issue I see is actually capturing the keys and saving them.

Comment: Why not have a simple "Change Key Bindings" dialog. You then display the current mnemonic and accelerator by using a combo box for the InputEvent and KeyEvent. Then user can then change the binding by selecting different values from the combo boxes. You could even do this in a simple table format for all Actions that contain your custom Key Bindings so the user can change all the values at one time and see the current values to avoid confusion.

Comment: @camickr, Thanks for the suggestion. I was thinking of the different ways I could go about this, and decided that I would like to prompt the user to enter in the short cut they would like to use by listening to their input, primarily to stick with convention. The application I am working on is a game (or at least an editor for one), and thought that it would be best to use the same methods as other games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to setup a [`KeyListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html). When the user presses/releases a key, it triggers a `KeyEvent` from which you can retrieve the main key pressed (e.g. <kbd>S</kbd>) and the mask/modifiers (e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>).

From there you can create a `KeyStroke` object and set this as the new accelerator of your menu.

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
   KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(e.getKeyCode(), e.getModifiers());
   menuItem.setAccelerator(ks);
}
```

The thing is you probably want this key listener to be removed right after the key released event, to avoid multiple keystrokes to be captured. So you could have this kind of logic:

```
JButton captureKeyButton = new JButton("Capture key");
JLabel captureText = new JLabel("");
KeyListener keyListener = new KeyAdapter(){
   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
       KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(e.getKeyCode(), e.getModifiers());
       menuItem.setAccelerator(ks);
       captureText.setText("Key captured: "+ks.toString());
       captureKeyButton.removeKeyListener(this);
   }
};
ActionListener buttonClicked = new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       captureKeyButton.addKeyListener(keyListener);
       captureText.setText("Please type a menu shortcut");
   }
};
captureKeyButton.addActionListener(buttonClicked);
```

Comment: I like the de-bounce logic. :-)

Comment: The concepts in this are perfect. I played around with it a little bit to fit my exact needs, but this was really only in how objects linked up.

Thanks for that, definitely what I was looking for.